# Как выбрать вариант в выпадающем меню? puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Всех приветствую! На двух разных выпадающих списках срабатывает, на третьем выпадающем списке - ноль реакции (ничего не происходит, но и ошибки не выдаёт)

js:

```
let page = await browser.newPage();
const select = require('puppeteer-select')

await page.select('#ColumnSeparator', ',')
await page.select('#ImportRemainsType', 'remains')
```

`await page.select('#Encoding', 'UTF-8')` // ноль реакции, и никаких ошибок

html:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-not-modified" id="ColumnSeparator" name="ColumnSeparator" ng-init="import.importProductSettings.ColumnSeparator=';'" ng-model="import.importProductSettings.ColumnSeparator">
    <option value=",">Запятая</option>
    <option value=" ">Символ табуляции</option>
    <option selected="selected" value=";">Точка с запятой</option>
    <option value="custom">Другое</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-not-modified" id="ImportRemainsType" name="ImportRemainsType" ng-init="import.importProductSettings.ImportRemainsType='normal'" ng-model="import.importProductSettings.ImportRemainsType">
   <option selected="selected" value="normal">Обычный режим</option>
   <option value="remains">Пополнение остатков</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-not-modified" id="Encoding" name="Encoding" ng-init="import.importProductSettings.Encoding='Windows-1251'" ng-model="import.importProductSettings.Encoding">
   <option selected="selected" value="Windows-1251">Windows-1251</option>
   <option value="UTF-8">UTF-8</option>
   <option value="UTF-16">UTF-16</option>
   <option value="KOI8-R">KOI8-R</option>
</select>
```

Как я могу поступить, чтобы выбрать в последнем выпадающем меню (#Encoding) пункт UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решил, было два элемента с id #Encoding, один из которых (первый) был **скрыт**:

[image: предупреждение о наличии двух элементов с неуникальным id]

Нужно обратиться ко второму элементу, так:

```
    const elem = (await page.$$('#Encoding'))[1]
    await elem.click()
    await page.keyboard.press("ArrowDown")
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter")
```

При обращении по id #Encoding, **обращение происходило, естественно, к первому элементу**, который был скрыт.

1. С помощью метода page.$$ я выбрал ВСЕ элементы с данным id и указал индекс 1, чтобы обратиться ко второму элементу (индекс первого элемента 0, индекс второго элемента 1, нам требуется второй, поэтому пишем индекс 1) положил их в переменную elem.
2. Кликнул на второй элемент.
3. С помощь метода puppeteer прописал нажатие клавиши "стрелка вниз".
4. С помощь метода puppeteer прописал нажатие клавиши "ентер".

Готово!